# What is the difference between these two brachot?

Tags: blessing, hebrew, shemoneh-esrei, maariv

During *Shacharit* (the morning service) and *Ma'ariv* (the evening service), these are two blessings that seem quite similar.  After the *Shema*, one says "Baruch ata Hashem, go-al Yisrael."

A few minutes later, during the *Shemona Esrai*, one says "Baruch ata Hashem, go-ail Yisrael."  In both cases, my *siddur* translates this as "Praised are You Hashem, Redeemer of [the people] Israel."

Is this merely a difference in tense or aspect?  Which one means what?  Is there any *drash* or other commentary that expands on this difference and its significance?

I wrote these blessings transliterated because I do not know how to type Hebrew with *nekudot* (necessary for this question to make sense).  If anyone wants to edit that in, you are welcome to.

Comment: Shoot, I didn't find [this duplicate](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26440/what-is-the-difference-between-the-blessing-of-gaal-yisrael-preceding-shemoneh) until after I posted this question.

Comment: Mike, no problem! Now hopefully the next person will have an easier time finding his question.